# How to specify base interface with net5 OpenAPI support

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, nswag, .net-5

I am trying to adapt a project to .net5 and want to use the new feature of adding an OpenAPI service reference. As far as I understand it, NSwag will be used to generate the client. I already used NSwag for this purpose in the past and I could use the *clientBaseInterface* option to specify the base interface of the client interface, i.e.

```
interface IClient: **IClientBase** {}
class Client: IClient {}
```

see also https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2772.

I tried to use the following configuration for my .net5 project but no base interface will be specified for the generated types:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <OpenApiReference Include="openapi.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Namespace="MyNamespace">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ClassName>MyOpenApiClient</ClassName>
      <OutputPath>MyOpenApiClient.cs</OutputPath>
      <Options>/GenerateClientInterfaces:true /UseBaseUrl:false /ExceptionClass:OpenApiException /ClientBaseInterface:MyBaseInterface</Options>
    </OpenApiReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Does anybody know how this option can be used out of the .net project file?

**Update:**
Since NSwag is creating partial classes and interfaces, a simple workaround is to just add the IClientBase interface in the partial interface, i.e.

```
// partial extension
partial interface IClient : **IClientBase** {}

// generated code
partial interface IClient {}
partial class Client: IClient {}
```

However, it still would be interesting to find out if we can manage this directly in the .net project file.